# PHP Advanced Search

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently making a website where I require a very advanced search engine. I want the users to be able to say `Person @ company` or `Product @ Category`. How would I detect the @ sign or any special characters, filter them out and make individual variables based on the returned string. So `$a = Person` and `$b = company`.

Comment: i believe this is just a simple parsing problem not an 'advanced search' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to split a string:

```
$items = explode('@', 'Person @ Company', 2);

if(count($items) === 2) {
    // Person @ Company
    $person = trim($items[0]);
    $company = trim($items[1]);
    // Do your searching here...
} else {
    // Search normally, not Person @ Company.
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Was just looking through the manual to find how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Send it across as a get request formatted as a=Person&b=company etc.  The other way is exactly what you said, loop through the string and examine the chars one by one.  When you encounter an @ sign you know that the letters before it (not including spaces) are the value of a and everything after the @ (not including spaces) is the value of b.

Sorry I tried to be as clear as I could.

Comment: Ok thanks! I would like to send it as a POST just for security so I will work on your second option. Thanks!!

Comment: *Send it as ... POST just for security* \*facepalm\*

Comment: @Joseph, Sending something as a POST request adds NO SECURITY over a corresponding GET request.  Download the tamperdata plugin for Firefox as an example to see how trivial is for a user to manipulate a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to achieve;

```
function searchForPersonAtCompany($searchQuery) {
    global $db;

    $queryComponents = explode('@', $searchQuery, 2);

    if (count($queryComponents) != 2) {
        // '@' was not specified in the search query, return an empty array.
        return array();
    }

    $person = $queryComponents[0];
    $company = $queryComponents[1];

    $sql = 'SELECT p.id AS personId, c.id AS companyId FROM people p JOIN companies c ON p.company = c.id WHERE p.name LIKE :person AND c.name LIKE :company';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':person', $person);
    $stmt->bindValue(':company', $company);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

You didn't specify your database schema, so I had to guess that you have a `people` table and a `companies` table, with people related to the companys table with the `company` field.

```
Table: People
id | name              | company
--------------------------------------------
 1 | Alice             | 1
 2 | Bob               | 1
 3 | Charles           | 2

Table: Companies
id | name              
--------------------------------------------
 1 | Company A       
 2 | Company B
```

You will have to adapt the code for your purposes, but using my testing data, the following should work;

```
searchForPersonAtCompany('Alice@Company A');
searchForPersonAtCompany('Charles@Company B');
```

Notes:

- This is a very simple implementation of your search, you might be better looking into a database based search engine which can handle more complicated queries for the future.
- I have used PDO as the connection to my database (bindValue, exec, etc), you might be using something different. `:person` and `:company` are just variables in the SQL.